# Duda con diferencia al crear tablas, desde el diseñador sql server y desde codigo t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

He creado una tabla con T-SQL

```
CREATE TABLE Persona2
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key,
    Nombres varchar(100) NULL,
    Apellidos varchar(100) NULL,
    Fecha_Nacimiento date NULL,
    Balance numeric(18, 2) NULL,
    Id_Persona_Tipo int NULL,
    Id_Estatus tinyint NULL
)
```

Despues genere un script de esa misma tabla y me genero el siguiente codigo.

```
USE [CRUD_MVC]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Persona2]    Script Date: 22/02/2020 03:59:15 p. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Persona2](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Nombres] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Apellidos] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Fecha_Nacimiento] [date] NULL,
    [Balance] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [Id_Persona_Tipo] [int] NULL,
    [Id_Estatus] [tinyint] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Despues cree una tabla desde el diseñador de SQL Server con las mismas caracteristicas.

Despues genere el script

```
USE [CRUD_MVC]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Persona3]    Script Date: 22/02/2020 04:24:50 p. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Persona3](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Nombres] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Apellidos] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Fecha_Nacimiento] [date] NULL,
    [Balance] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [Id_Persona_Tipo] [int] NULL,
    [Id_Estatus] [tinyint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Persona3] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Despues compare ambos scripts generados y me di cuenta de una ligera diferencia en ambos casos, quisiera saber a que se debe esto.

[image: En cuanto a diferencias, no me refiero al nombre de la tabla]

Answer (score 2):

La diferencia es que en la primera sintaxis no se indica el nombre del índice creado.

```
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
```

Mientras que en la segunda es explícita.

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_Persona3] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

En la primera, SQL Server creará la clave primaria asignándole un nombre escogido por él, del tipo `PK__Persona2__3214EC07DCE7C37B`, mientras que en el segundo caso ya se especifica que el nombre será `PK_Persona3`

Comment: Y es buena costumbre siempre asignar nombres a las llaves (primarias, únicas y foráneas) y en general a todos los objetos.